# How to filter a string containing round brackets (or parenthesis) while using jsonpath?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath

js code is ....

```
var queryString = 'Dolphin Travels (Sagar Travels)';
var results = jsonPath(jsonvar, "$.availableTrips[?("+queryString+")]");
```

Error :

```
SyntaxError: jsonPath: unterminated string literal: _v.travels == 'Dolphin Travels (Sagar Travels)
```

[image]

Comment: was my answer helpful? please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's get some prerequisites figured out:

You are searching 'Dolphin Travels (Sagar Travels)', but I don't see this in your test data (at least that you've shown), so I can't really tell what part of the object/array it is in (whether it is a value or a key).

Here is the sample data I'm working with:

```
var t = {
    'availableTrips': [
        {
            'busType': 'Volvo A/C-Multi Axle Semi sleeper (2+2)',
            'busTypeId': '101',
            'fares': 250,
            'travels': 'SVR Tours and Travel [Citizen]'
        },
        {
            'busType': 'Lorem Ipsum',
            'busTypeId': '102',
            'fares': 300,
            'travels': 'SVR Tours and Travel [Citizen]'
        }
    ]
}
```

Simple usage of jsonPath (I'm also assuming you mean [this jsonPath library](https://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/), since you did not specify):

```
jsonPath(t,'$.availableTrips[?(/SVR/.test(@.travels))]');
```

Yields the array of objects in the `availableTrips` array since the string SVR (as a regex) is in both of them.

```
jsonPath(t,'$.availableTrips[?(/Volvo/.test(@.busType))]');
```

Yields only the first item in the `availableTrips` array, equivalent to `t.availableTrips[0]`.

---

Now, to answer your question:

When escaping, you can use a backslash `\`, but since you are in a string that is interpreted, you'll need to escape it TWICE: `\\`. Once for the string being sent as a parameter for `jsonParse` and again as part of the expression being interpreted within `jsonParse`. Like so:

```
jsonPath(t,'$.availableTrips[?(/\\(2\\+2\\)/.test(@.busType))]');
```

Notice that I also had to escape the `+` quantifier, as well as the `(` and `)` group metacharacters.

In terms of sanitizing user input, e.g. `var queryString = 'Dolphin Travels (Sagar Travels)';`, you can perform the following (see [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)):

```
var sanitizedQueryString = queryString.replace(/([\.\^\$\*\+\?\(\)\[\{\\\|])/g,'\\$1');
```